# How to pass an Array from Child component to Parent Component in react

Tags: reactjs

How to pass an Array from Child component to Parent Component in react 
this is my code

This is my Parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from '../Child/Child';

export default class Parent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child></Child>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This is Child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        const students = ['Mark','John'];
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: How will this be used? Short version is: parent passes a function to the child, child calls that function and passes in the array. But without knowing how you plan to use the array i can't give any more details on where/when/how to use that function.

Comment: Need to know ur goal, u can not set the parent props or state from child directly but you can pass a function to child and call this function from child. On parent component function u can do whatever u want

Answer (score 3):

Use React Components States and Props to achieve this:

**Parent:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from '../Child/Child';

export default class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: []} // Initialize the State
        this.onChildData = this.onChildData.bind(this); // Bind the helper method
    }

    /*
     * This method is just to update the state with new data incoming from Child
     * You can even inline this in your 'render' method
     */
    onChildData(data) {
        this.setState({data});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                /*
                 * Add a 'onData' prop to invoke from Child
                 * It will work as a callback
                 */
                <Child onData={this.onChildData}></Child>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const students = ['Mark','John'];

export default class Child extends Component {
    /**
     * componentDidMount is called by React immediately after this component is mounted
     * We use it to call the 'onData' callback and send data to the parent
     */
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onData(students);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: any way to do it without props?